# Yaml array of string to golang struct field

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to map dead simple yaml config file to struct with [this](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2) package with no success.

*config.yaml*

```
Drivers: 
  - "/Volumes/V1"
  - "/Volumes/V2"
```

*go*

```
type Iconfig struct {
    Drivers []string `yaml:"Drivers,flow"`
}

iconfig := Iconfig{}
uerr := yaml.UnmarshalStrict(config_yaml, iconfig)
```

`uerr`:

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value [recovered]
        panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

`fmt.Println(string(config_yaml))`:

```
Drivers: 
  - "/Volumes/V1"
  - "/Volumes/V2"
```

**Why `"/Volumes/V1"` is considered as unaddressable value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your line to this:

```
uerr := yaml.UnmarshalStrict(config_yaml, &iconfig)
```

Comment: omg, kill me.
Thank you for your time sir.